# Pasar fechas a una base de datos

Tags: sql, date

Estoy realizando un programa para registro de horas en un trabajo. Recojo los datos (concretamente la hora que me da problemas es 12:30 ) en un jtext como String. 
Transformo este String a Date y despúes lo envío a la base de datos.
Todo lo hace correcto y registra el dato, lo único que en lugar de guardar 12:30 me guarda 00:30 y no se porqué.
Os ruego a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.
Un saludo y gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Revisa el formato de hora, que no este en 24/H porque el 00:30 hace referencia a las 12:30 AM, y segun entiendo la hora que estas ingresando es en la tarde

Comment: pudes sarle un **select campo_de_fecha from tabla** y presentar el resultado

Comment: Kevin Restrepo gracias, en teoria no he indicado nada, ni AM ni PM, creo que por defecto aplica el formato de 24 h. Verdad? o debo indicar el formato?

Comment: DavElsanto ¿Te refieres para ver que formato me devuelve, si 24h o AM - PM?

Comment: Grarcias DavElsanto, tenías razón. Al revisar el código me he dado cuenta que había indicado formato hh:mm (Am-pm) en lugar de formato HH:mm que es para formato 24h. Gracias. Solucionado.